# move in move out tween animation for group of movieclips using as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have set of 6 movieclips as array_0 and another set of 6 movieclips as array_1. It is like two choices for different screens. Both these arrays are nested in another array as all_array. all 12 movieclips are positioned to a same x and y at initial load and that is outside the visible stage. I would like to use two different global variables for indexing. for example, cCat_Sel which ranges from 0-5 and another cScr_Sel ranges from 0-1. cCat_Sel will be changed on a click event of six buttons separate objects on stage (each button for each category).

so it will show the content for each category as per the value of cScr_Sel. if cScr_Sel is 0 then it will use all_array[0][cCat_Sel] to access the current target and similarly respective array for value of 1 as all_array[1][cCat_Sel]

I have done all the work including all tween animations to move current target and make it visible. But the tween does not bring the second set of mcs to visible area. I have two functions one for movein and one for move out by using tween animation for mc.x property. every relevant click event; I have to move current mc out and make alpha 0 and once that is finished, move in new current target and make alpha 1.

Somehow I have to combine these two tweens in one function. This is the part that I am stuck. or may be putting these mcs in two different arrays not a correct approach. I can easily achieve what I want on Enter Frame event of the root to check for cCat_Sel and cScr_Sel variables and do both animations one after the other but it seems like enter frame uses too much of cpu and makes it slower and probably not preferable.

willing to try anybody's suggestions or guidance. Thanks in advance.
I do not have any formal or informal programming education at all but I make things work by reading and trying out few things as per stackoverflow question and answers and sometime google. because most of my answers I have found from stack overflow.
Update:

```
        function fnSlideInOut(cMc:Object, pMc:Object){
        var HideX:Number =650;
        var ShowX:Number = 0;
        if(cMc != null){
            if(cMc.x != ShowX){
                //cMc.alpha = 1;
                var SlideMcIn:Tween = new Tween(cMc, "x", Strong.easeOut, 650, ShowX, 0.5, true);
                SlideMcIn.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, fnSlideInFinish);
                SlideMcIn.start();
            }
        }
        if(pMc != null){
            if(pMc.x != HideX){
                //pMc.alpha = 1;
                var SlideMcOut:Tween = new Tween(pMc, "x", Strong.easeOut, 0, HideX, 0.5, true);
                SlideMcOut.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, fnSlideOutFinish);
                SlideMcOut.start();
            }
        }

        function fnSlideOutFinish(e:TweenEvent){
            //SlideMcOut.obj.alpha = 0;
            SlideMcOut.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, fnSlideOutFinish);
            }
        function fnSlideInFinish(e:TweenEvent){
            //SlideMcIn.obj.alpha = 1;
            SlideMcIn.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, fnSlideInFinish);
            }
    }//End Function
fnSlideInOut(cScr_Sel, pScr_Sel);
```

I would like expert like you to comment on any kind of errors for the above code. It works 99 times but 1 time the movieclip either does not reach the destination or current and previous both targets showing and that too not where they are suppose to. This only happens when button click event happens in a quick succession. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A option could be to use a third party library like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). It will then make it easy for you to run your second animation right after the first one is complete:

```
private function startAnimation():void
{
    var mcToHide:MovieClip = all_array[cScr_Sel][cCat_Sel];
    TweenLite.to(mcToHide, 1, {x: HIDDEN_X_POSITION, y:HIDDEN_Y_POSITION, alpha:0, onComplete:finishAnimation});
}

private function finishAnimation():void
{
    var mcToShow:MovieClip = all_array[(cScr_Sel + 1) % 2][cCat_Sel];
    TweenLite.to(mcToShow, 1, {x: VISIBLE_X_POSITION, y:VISIBLE_Y_POSITION, alpha:1});
}
```

You can then call `startAnimation()` on a relevant mouse click event and after having set `cScr_Sel` and `cCat_Sel` accordingly to your needs.

Comment: I looked at the tweenLite link and it seems that I need some time to jump into it. but seems like it is very thorough. I am sure that will help me in a long run. I kept seeing tweenlite in other websites as well. I looked at some of the possibilities. Its simply amazing and sky is the limit. built in Tween of Flash is so primitive and so full of garbage. I will upload a solution if I can make it workable using built in Tween class. Thanks a lot for quick answer and showing the correct way to deal with the situation.

Comment: Well, from my experience you don't really need time to jump into TweenLite and start to use it. Apart from adding the imports to my sample, that is about everything you need to do. I'm glad it helps you anyway

Comment: Thanks again. I will eventually be using TweenLite for sure. I was also sure that your code would have worked. But here is something I made a quick solution. It is not great but it is a temporary solution for my Monday deadline.